# SharePoint 2007 and it's underlying operating systems

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, sharepoint-2007

We have a MOSS 2007 Standard farm, running on 2 Web Front End (WFE) and 1 Indexing server all running on 64 bit Windows Server 2003 servers.

We need to upgrade our servers to Windows Server 2008, and wanted to know if you can run 1 WFE on Windows 2008 and 1 WFE on Windows 2003, while we are in the process of upgrading our individual servers.

Comment: It's good you're on 64-bit already, as that will be needed for the 2010 version if/when that's needed.

Comment: Exactly.  This process of upgrading the servers to 2008 is the first step in the upgrade to 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I can not speak to whether you *can*, but you might consider running on just one 2003 server while upgrading the other, then switch to the new 2008 server while upgrading the first, then resuming your load-balanced architecture on homogeneous systems.

Comment: Thanks, that is something that we are considering.  However, because of the third indexing server, we wanted see what the possibility was of running the various servers in a mixed OS environment.